# How can I quit entering keywords when I auto-insert with Helm?

Tags: helm, completion, auto-insert

When I `M-x find-file RET file.el RET` and then run `M-x auto-insert`, I am eventually presented with a list of keywords that Helm will complete for me.  Trouble is, I have no idea how to *finish* the Helm completion without with *quitting* the entire function (with `C-g`).

How do I finish Helm completion and allow `auto-insert` to continue its work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I initially thought this was a Helm bug, but it tells you on the bottom of the Helm prompt:

```
C/M-RET:Empty
```

So, just hit `C-RET` or `M-RET` to finish `auto-insert`.

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah, I had figured it out by accident once upon a time, so I knew it had to be possible.  Don't know why I didn't see that banner :)

Comment: How to quit insert keywords when with ivy? :-(

Comment: At last, I know how to quit keywords inserting with ivy. Using `C-M-j`. :-(
https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/636